# What are pubs (UK public house) classed as according to the places API?

Tags: google-places-api

I see that the closest matches to limit a search I'm after are 'bar' and 'night_club'... however I'd also like to include something like 'public_house'.

It's not on the supported list but I'd love to find a way to narrow down my API call to focus on these three types. My worry is someone will respond with 'restaurant' or 'family_eatery' or something which isn't strictly the case and opens me up to way more calls than necessary.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just popping in to say that I've continued to dig into this and I still can't figure it out. If you 'use' google maps it definitely hightlights 'Pub' now underneath the venue information, but as far as I can see that just fires off a search for 'Pub'. I'm assuming they're using the rest of the data they have to make this association without it being in the Places API as a type. - Genuinely, if anyone has any idea how to do this I will be eternally grateful :)